# Jest simulate click through nested function

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

i am confused while i was writing test on nested functions.Here is code example.

```
 export const selectedItemFunc = (selectedLabel, selectedItem, item, mapSelectedItems) => {
      selectedItem.push(item);
      mapSelectedItem(selectedLabel, selectedItem, mapSelectedItems);
    };

  export const renderItemsList = (selectedLabel, filteredItems, selectedItem, mapSelectedItems) => {
          if (filteredItems && filteredItems.length) {
            return filteredItems.map((item) => {
              const checkedStatus = selectedItem && selectedItem.length ? selectedItem.filter((status) => status.value === item.value).length : false;
              return (
                <div
                  className="neighborhoodItemsContainer"
                  key={Math.random()}
                  onClick={() => checkedStatus ? removeSelectedItems(selectedLabel, selectedItem, item, mapSelectedItems) : selectedItemFunc(selectedLabel, selectedItem, item, mapSelectedItems)}
                >
                  <Col md="12">
                    <Row>
                      {renderCheckedIcon(checkedStatus, item)}
                    </Row>
                  </Col>
                </div>);
            });
          }
          return null;
        };
```

Btw here is my component:

```
 <Row>
              <Collapse
                isOpen={props.visibleItem}
                className="neighborhoodCollapse"
              >
                <Card className="neighborhoodExpandCard">
                  <CardBody className="neighborhoodCardBody">
                    {renderItemsList(props.label, props.itemList, props.selectedItem, props.mapSelectedItems)}
                  </CardBody>
                </Card>
              </Collapse>
            </Row>
```

I want to write test for onClick method.If `checkedStatus` is false ,i checked whether `selectedItemFunc` function is called or not.So that i am writing test like this:

```
describe('', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
   props = {
      openCollapse: jest.fn(),
      mapSelectedItems: jest.fn(),
      label: '',
      visibleItem: false,
      selectedItem: [],
      itemList: [
        { value: 'G1', label: 'G1', title: 'Regions', filterTitle: 'regions' }],
    };
    wrapper = shallow(<SelectableFiltering {...props} />);
})
 it('', () => {
      const button = wrapper.find('.neighborhoodItemsContainer');
      button.simulate('click');
      expect(selectedItemFunc).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

But i have get an error like this:

```
expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

    jest.fn() value must be a mock function or spy.
    Received:
      function: [Function selectedItemFunc]
```

if you can review these codes and you said to me places that i made mistakes , i would be very pleased.Thanks.

Comment: selectedItemFunc isn't defined anywhere in your test

Comment: Also, this `key={Math.random()}` is a bad idea. It will force a re-render every time render is hit, even if it is unnecessary. It defeats the purpose of reacts diffing engine.